# Build different APKs for different environments (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

We're building a Xamarin.Android application that connects to the cloud.
We have different Cloud URLs for different environments, namely Development, Staging and Production.
I find myself manually changing URLs everytime I generate an APK for a particular environment.
I came across Gradle/ANT ways of changing "flavours" but since it is not available in Xamarin, How do I go about it? How does one manage different environments in Xamarin? Is it using MSBuild config files? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
What I currently have:

```
 /// <summary>
///     The application URL for PROD
/// </summary>
//private const string ApplicationUrl = "https://prod.azure-mobile.net/";

/// <summary>
///     The application URL for DEV
/// </summary>
private const string ApplicationUrl = "https://dev.azure-mobile.net/";
```

In this case, we manually comment/uncomment URLs for different builds (Dev/Staging/Prod) and generate APKs. I understand it's not an optimal solution and is prone to mistakes.

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for using [T4 Text Transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). Can you include some sample/pseudocode code for what you are trying to achieve? That will give me something to work off to build a sample for you.

Comment: Also, how do you differentiate between a Development/Staging/Production build? Is it a manual process or flagged by an auto-build system like Bamboo or Jenkins?

Comment: @MattR It is a manual process(No bamboo/jenkins involved). Added pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably define different build configurations (in the Project Options) for Development, Staging and Production. You could then define symbols (in the Compiler page of the options) and use preprocessor directives to change the definition of ApplicationUrl in the code. Building each one is then just a matter of selecting the appropriate configuration in the drop-down.

I'd also change the output path for each configuration so the APKs get written to different folders to reduce any possible confusion about which configuration each APK is built with.

Disadvantage is that if you change any other project options you need to ensure you make the change for every configuration, but as this isn't done very often it's probably a reasonable compromise.